# How do I trigger the "Staff of Magnus" quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am playing Skyrim for PS3, and after completing a quest "Good Intentions" for the College of Winterhold, I was told about Mirrabelle Ervine could trigger the quest "Staff of Magnus". He talked about her but no quest came up, and when I spoke to her she had no option to ask about the Staff of Magnus. Is this fixable? Because I have tried reloading it, and I even started all the way back to the quest "Hitting the Books". Nothing I tried worked.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. The Uesp has nothing on a bug like this, though.

Answer (score 2):

You must have the "Revealing the Unseen" and "Containment" quests completed to trigger "The Staff of Magnus".

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Good_Intentions

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Revealing_the_Unseen

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Containment

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Staff_of_Magnus